# How can I have the same progress with multiple downloading for metro windows app?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I try to make metro app for windows store. At the start of the app I try to download many files. And during the download I would like one progress bar for all the downloading files. So I try to adapt [Background-Transfer-Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Transfer-Sample-d7833f61) cause in this sample all files have their own progress and not only one for all.
So for moment I have the progress bar which is progressing for only one by one file.
How can I have the same progress with multiple downloading for metro windows app?
A part of my code:

```
StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFolder dataFolder = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Contenu", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
var backgroundDownloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
foreach (var img in contentToDownload)
            {
                loadingBar.Value = 0;
                var uri = new Uri(img);
                StorageFile newFile = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync(Path.GetFileName(img), CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                DownloadOperation downloadOperation = backgroundDownloader.CreateDownload(uri, newFile);
                await HandleDownloadAsync(downloadOperation);
            }


private async Task HandleDownloadAsync(DownloadOperation downloadOperation)
        {
            var progress = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(ProgressCallback);
            await downloadOperation.StartAsync().AsTask(progress);
        }

private void ProgressCallback(DownloadOperation obj)
        {
            double progress
            = ((double)obj.Progress.BytesReceived / obj.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive);
            loadingBar.Value = progress * 100;
            Debug.WriteLine((int)loadingBar.Value);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In a while I found a workaround on this.
here's the workaround.

first declare this on the top of your code

```
private List<DownloadOperation> allDownloads = new List<DownloadOperation>();
private List<ResponseInformation> responseList = new List<ResponseInformation();
private ulong TOTALBYTES = 0;
private ulong BYTES = 0;
```

inside your function ProgressCallback add this line of code

```
private void ProgressCallback(DownloadOperation obj)
{
   TOTALBYTES += obj.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive;
   BYTES += obj.Progress.BytesReceived;
}
```

and then inside the function HandleDownloadAsync add this code

```
private async Task HandleDownloadAsync(DownloadOperation downloadOperation)
{
   allDownloads.Add(downloadOperation);
   ResponseInformation response = downloadOperation.GetResponseInformation();
   if (response.StatusCode == 200)
    {
      responseList.Add(response);
    }
    if (responseList.Count() == allDownloads.Count())
      {
        var total = BYTES * 100 / TOTALBYTES;
        if (total == 100)
         {
             // do the success message here
         }
      }     
}
```

Hope this will help .